# Why does the equation Sqrt[x] Sqrt[x] == -1 have a solution?

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

When I try to solve the following equation, Mathematica gives a solution for which the equation is not defined:

```
Reduce[Sqrt[x] Sqrt[x] == -1, x]
```

> x == -1

and when I try to plot the function `Plot[Sqrt[x] Sqrt[x], {x, -10, 10}]`, Mathematica merrily plots negative values for $x$ as well.

Why does it happen, and what can I do so that Mathematica will provide "correct" answers?

Comment: [`Sqrt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt.html) works with complex arguments as well. Perhaps you wanted [`Surd[x, 2]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html) to find the real-valued n-root? What is the "correct" answer in your opinion?

Comment: I think that `Reduce` doesn't get a chance to 'see' `Sqrt[x] Sqrt[x]`; instead, it 'sees' `x`; same with `Plot`

Comment: @MarcoB
Your comment seems to be the answer I was seeking. I assumed that since by default 'Reduce' solves over a domain of reals (or, at least the answer didn't change when I explicitly requested a solution over 'Reals'), everything else is also done over reals. Obviously this was a wrong assumption. I am curious if the documentation provides an explanation about such kind of things so that the next time I won't have to guess.

Comment: @Daniel Glad it helped. Notice also that `Reduce`, and in general any Mathematica function, works on *complex* numbers by default. See e.g. `Reduce[x^2 == -1, x]` vs `Reduce[x^2 == -1, x, Reals]`.